# Supremum of $\{-x : x \in A \}$ using the $\varepsilon$-definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $B = \{-x : x \in A \}$ and let $A$ be a bounded set with $\sup(A) = 3$. Show that $\inf(B) =-3$.

I need to show this using the epsilon definition for infimum. Now since $3 \ge x$ $\forall x \in A$ we have that $-3 \le -x$ $\forall x \in A$ so $-3$ is a lower bound for $B$.

Now I need to show that $\forall \varepsilon >0$ $-x < -3 +\varepsilon$ holds. The trick here seems to be to get an equivalent form for $-x < -3 +\varepsilon$ that we know is true, but I cannot seem to come up with this. Is $$-x < -3 +\varepsilon \iff 3> x+ \varepsilon$$ true since $3 \ge x$ for any $x \in A$ due to the sup of $A$ being $3$?

Answer (score 3):

We want to show:

> For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $y\in B$ such that $y<-3+\epsilon$.

Unraveling the definition of $B$, this is equivalent to:

> For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $x\in A$ such that $-x<-3+\epsilon$.

This, in turn, is equivalent to:

> For each $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $x\in A$ such that $x>3-\epsilon$.

However, this is exactly what $\sup(A)=3$ is saying.

Answer (score 1):

No, you *don't* need to show that $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $-x<-3+\varepsilon$, which is good, since it doesn't make sense. What you have to show is that $\forall\varepsilon>0$, *there is* some $x\in A$ such that $-x<-3+\varepsilon$. But this is equivalent to $x>3-\varepsilon$ and, since $3=\sup A$, there is such a $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already shown that it is bounded, then it has infimo, so let $c=\inf(B)$. Also since the supreme of $A$ is $3$, then, for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x_\epsilon\in A$ such that $x_\epsilon\geq3-\epsilon$. So:
\begin{align*}
x_\epsilon&\geq3-\epsilon\\
-x_\epsilon&\leq-3+\epsilon.
\end{align*}
But $c=\inf(B)\leq-x_\epsilon\leq-3+\epsilon\Rightarrow c\leq-3+\epsilon$, and so applying $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ we have $c\leq-3$. So together with what you already have you get to $\inf(B)=c=-3$.